# Merging objects in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yee4b1uu/27/).

```
$('#send').click(function(){
    var object = {}; 
    var chat = {};
    chat = {msg:$('#message').val()};
    var pic = $('.pic');
    object = pic.map(function(){
         var src = $(this).attr('src'),
             tid = $(this).data('id'),
           title = $(this).attr('title'); 
         return  {src:src,tid:tid,title:title}       
      }).get();
    var newobj = $.extend(chat,object);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(newobj));
});
```

The code combines two objects `chat` and `object` into one single object. This is how it looks like after `JSON.stringify`

```
 {"0":{"src":"pic.jpg","tid":3,"title":"logo"},
  "1":{"src":"pic2.jpg","tid":3,"title":"logo2"},
  "msg":"dfdfdf"
 }
```

Is it possible to merge the objects into this:

```
 {
  "0":{"msg":"dfdfdf"},
  "1":{"src":"pic.jpg","tid":3,"title":"logo"},
  "2":{"src":"pic2.jpg","tid":3,"title":"logo2"}
 }
```

I have tried `chat[0] = {msg:$('#message').val()};` and `map` function but it doesn't even merge the `chat` object into the `object` object.

HTML:

```
  <div class="area">
  <button>Choose Picture</button>
</div>
```

Comment: why not to use array instead object? `{'0': {msg}}` -> `[{msg}]` ?

Comment: `object.unshift(chat);` http://jsfiddle.net/yee4b1uu/28/  ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could delete and reinsert it

```
var newobj = $.extend(chat,object);
delete newobj.msg; // delete the property
newobj["0"] = chat; // add the property
console.log(JSON.stringify(newobj));
```

And since you're using Numbers as the property names or identifiers, it would be better suited if it were an `Array` instead of an `Object`.